# update not throwing integrity error (OneToOneField)

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, one-to-one

[image: POST parameters]
[image: Database data]

Update not giving me integrity error on one-to-one-field key:

**Model looks like:**

```
store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
credit_type = models.OneToOneField(CreditType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
value = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0)
```

**and api looks like:**

```
curd = 'add'
operate = {'add': operator.add, 'delete': operator.sub}
try:
    for index, c_id in enumerate(credit_ids):
        StoreCredits.objects.filter(store_id=store_id, credit_type_id=c_id)\
            .update(value=operate[curd](F('value'), credit_values[index]))
except IntegrityError:
    return {"wrong key entered try again."}
return {"success"}
```

Other info: The api function has: `@transaction.atomic`, and amn't converting POST values to int, though database has int types, 

It works fine simply adds deletes values, but i want to handle wrong ids. **With foreign key** it throws integrity error when wrong id is passed, here it throws no error error simply returns `'success'`
it simply adds values to credit_ids that matches and does nothing with other

Comment: Did you tried it through `Django Shell` ?

Comment: am sending data through postman, have no idea of django shell

Comment: I don't understand what integrity error you are expecting to get here. All you're doing is updating an integer field, which is not unique.

Comment: here the credit id is mapped to id in database image, what i have is a credit-type in masters table and then credit type field of store credit table maps it via one to one key, What i want if, in case if someone tries to add credit-type value for a credit type that doesn't exists in master credit type table, then it should throw and error (like in foreign key it throws integrity error when you try to add data to a foreign key that doesn't exist in masters)

Comment: if a id does not exist in the master table, it should throw error rather than just skipping over them. and am using one to one field rather than foreign key, that is all i want because i want foreign key with unique=true but while making migrations django gave me warning to use one to one field rather than foreign key

Comment: But none of this code does anything to *add* a value for a credit type. All it does is update existing ones. So there is no possibility of violating database integrity here.

Comment: oh! yes id updates, sorry my bad! thankyou @DanielRoseman